# Java - Storing Strings to Login

Tags: java, string, authentication, account

I have a task to do which involves asking the user to input their last name and giving the user an account number to login to the program. I have listed the steps below which might make more sense.

1) User creates an account

2) User enters their last name

3) User is given an account number

4) User can then login using their last name and account number

A user enters their last name and they are given an account number which they then use to login to deposit, withdraw and check balance.

How do i create a programe to do this without the use of database?

**Account Class**

```
private static int number = 500;

Account(){

    accountNumber = number++;
}
```

**Create Account Class**

```
public void createAccount(){

    String firstName;

    System.out.print("Please Enter Last Name: ");
    lastName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("This is your Account Number to log into: " + _______ );
}

public void logIn(){

    System.out.println("Please enter your last name: ");

    System.out.println("Please enter your account number: ");

}
```

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt A user enters their last name and they are given an account number which they then use to login to deposit, withdraw and check balance

Answer (score 0):

Start with the account. It should be constructed only given a name (the lastname) and have some fields for the account number and balance.

Quickstart:

```
public class Account 
{
    private static int number = 500;

    private int accountNumber; 
    private int balance = 0; //(in cents or a float if this is in full dollars)
    private String name;

    public Account(String name){
        accountNumber = number++;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getBalance(){
        return this.balance;
    }

    public boolean withdrawMoney(int amount){
        if(this.balance < amount)
            return false;
        this.balance -= amount;
        return true;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber(){
        return this.accountNumber;
    }
}
```

Then for each entered name create an account for that user, then do whatever you want with it.

```
public void createAccount(){

    System.out.print("Please Enter Last Name: ");
    String lastName = scanner.nextLine();

    /* Create an account */
    Account account = new Account(lastName);

    /* TODO: Save all accounts into a ArrayList<Account> to keep track of them */

    System.out.println("This is your Account Number to log into: " + account.getAccountNumber());
}

public void logIn(){

    System.out.println("Please enter your last name: ");
    String lastName = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter your account number: ");
    String accountNumber = scanner.nextLine();

    /* TODO: Convert accountNumber to an int */

    /* TODO: Check if an account exists in that list of saved accounts which has
       that lastName and that account number 
    */

    /* TODO: Add interaction with the bank account */
}
```

You should figure out the rest for yourself. For the "database" of accounts, you could simply use a `static ArrayList<Account> allAccounts` which is declared and initialized somewhere in the UI class. Or you can offload that to a seperate "Container" class that does that for you.

Comment: /* TODO: Check if an account exists in that list of saved accounts which has that lastName and that account number.... How would i do this could you guide me ?

Comment: If you had a `ArrayList<Account> allAccounts` of all the accounts you could simple iterate over them in a `for(Account acc : allCounts)` and check if `acc.getName().equals(lastName)` and at the same time `acc.getAccountNumber() == _accountNumber` (where `_accountNumber` is of type `int`)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a java noob. I don't understand what you mean. Could you code it? It's for a school task.

Comment: No, the above gives the basics, you can look up the rest on the internet with enough effort.

Comment: I been looking and i can't find anything. Can you please help

Comment: StackOverflow is no coding service, we're here to help with concrete coding problems. For starters, have a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_add.htm . Else, revise the basics of Java.